# Uncaught ReferenceError: global is not defined node.js

Tags: javascript, nodejs

Tengo una aplicacion web, un chat para ser mas precisos. Necesito declarar una variable de tipo global cuyo contenido pueda ver tanto en el frontEnd.js como en el server.js.

El código que estoy utlizando es el siguiente:

```
global.name = 'El chat del front';
 console.log(global.name);
```

Y en el server.js se usa asi:

```
console.log('El chat desde el server ' + global.name);
```

Alguna sugerencia?